# Module Endomorphism that sends 1 to 0 is zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let k be a field and A be a k-algebra, with $\phi$ as an endomorphism for A as an A-module. If $\phi$ sends 1 to 0, then does it mean that $\phi$ is zero? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Because $\phi(a)=\phi(a\cdot 1)=a\cdot \phi(1)=0$

Comment: Why ϕ(ax1)=axϕ(1)? I mean a might be a matrix or something else.